# ¿Por qué en algunas voces del Diccionario de Autoridades aparece la entrada repetida entre paréntesis?

Tags: dle

En el [Diccionario de Autoridades](https://apps2.rae.es/DA.html) en algunos casos, después de la palabra de la entrada, aparece repetida entre paréntesis. Por ejemplo:

[image]

¿A que se debe esa duplicación entre paréntesis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según el prólogo:
[image]

[image]

Lo escribo aquí a mi manera: Atendiendo a que en las fundiciones (fuente de la letra) de esta especie no hay acentos, y que podrían hacer falta para noticia del modo de pronunciar la voz, se ha tomado el medio de que en los artículos en que van repetidas por algún motivo, se les ponen allí los acentos que les corresponden, y en los que no hay esta oportunidad se repiten en minúscula entre paréntesis y se les ponen los acentos que necesitan.

En la versión web esas tildes han desaparecido, pero en la versión impresa parece que se puede distinguir alguna señal.

Espero que ayude.

Comment: De hecho en la versión impresa esta palabra está escrito "pedréra", dos veces `[ver](https://books.google.com/books?id=2reM6MluCBsC&q=pedrera#v=snippet&q=pedrera&f=false).